# Issue with using like with a wildcard in dynamic SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, sql-like

I am trying to use a dynamic SQL statement in a stored procedure to filter a query depending on the input from a user. I am starting basic with just one parameter that needs to find matching forenames in the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspFilter
    @FirstName varchar(100) = null,
    @Debug bit = 1
AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Params nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(300);

SELECT @Params = N'@FirstName varchar(300) = null'
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1=1'

IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL
    SELECT @Search = N'@FirstName' + N'%'''
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N' AND Forename LIKE ''' + @Search

IF @Debug = 1
    @PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @Params, @FirstName = @FirstName;
GO

EXEC dbo.uspFilter @FirstName = 'Test', @Debug = 1;
GO
```

The output of the debug statement looks correct but it is not returning any results:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1=1 AND Forename LIKE '@FirstName%'
```

EDIT: This is a meant to be a trimmed down version of what I am looking for - I will be using multiple parameters with different search criteria.

Comment: You are using the variable name, not the value of the variable `@FirstName`. But you don't need to (and shouldn't) use dynamic sql to make searches, it is vulnerable to SQL injection and syntax errors as you have already seen.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but your looking for someone who's first name starts with `@Firstname`?

Comment: That's why you should *not* use dynamic SQL. In this case you don't even need it, you could write a SELECT statement with `set @search = '%' + @FirstName + '%'; SELECT ... WHERE Forename like @search`

Comment: In any case stored procedures with "dynamic filters" more often than not **harm** performance. The server creates an execution plan based on the values used in the first execution. If, for example, 90% of entries have an empty FirstName the generated plan will probably scan the entire table. That will hurt performance when you try to search for a non-empty name

Comment: Apologies if I have not been clear - this is the first step of a procedure that will be using multiple input parameters and will need to build the SQL string depending on which inputs are given. I'm starting with just the first input to make it simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you need to do it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspFilter
    @Search varchar(300) = null,
    @Debug bit = 1
AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Params nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Params = N'@FirstName varchar(300)';
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [Table]';

IF @FirstName IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N' WHERE Forename LIKE @FirstName + ''%'';';
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N';';
END

IF @Debug = 1
    PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @Params, @FirstName = @Search;
GO

EXEC dbo.uspFilter @Search = 'Steve', @Debug = 1;
```

Note that although Crowcoder's comment about SQL Injection is important, you can write dynamic SQL that doesn't allow for Injection. Such as the above.

Edit: Couple of slight corrections.

Comment: There's no need for dynamic SQL for such a query. The branch that performs a pattern search could be replaced with `set @search = '%' + @FirstName + '%'; SELECT ... WHERE Forename like @search`

Comment: Yes, I agree, Dynamic SQL can be completely avoided here, @PanagiotisKanavos. i was more showing the OP how they would do this using dynamic SQL, but please do post, as an answer, for how to not use it entirely. it'll be good for the OP as well.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what the query is supposed to do if FirstName is empty. And "dynamic filters" are performance killers in the first place

Comment: Thank you @Larnu . I have adapted this for my query and it is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspFilter
    @Search varchar(300) = null,
    @Debug bit = 1
AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Params nvarchar(max);

SELECT @Params = N'@FirstName varchar(300)';
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [YourTable]';

IF @Search IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N' WHERE Forename LIKE @FirstName;';
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N';';
END

IF @Debug = 1
    PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @Params, @FirstName = @Search;
GO
EXEC dbo.uspFilter @Search = 'Rameshbhai%', @Debug = 1;
go
```

pass parameter with wildcard values like 'searchtext%'

Answer (score -1):

You can also apply dynamic where condition as below without make dynamic query, please have look at below sample example. You can join other filter by applying AND where clause with below example.

```
Declare @firstName VARCHAR(50)='sa'

SELECT
    *
FROM Table 
WHERE 
(
    (Forename LIKE '%'+@firstName+'%' AND @firstName!='') 
    OR 
    (@firstName='')
)
```